# How do you get good contrast with Canon Matte Photo Paper?

Tags: printing, paper, contrast, color-black

I'm trying to print on Canon Matte Photo paper from my Pixma Pro-1.  Printing on Luster and Glossy paper works great, but when specifying that I'm printing on Canon Matte Photo paper, the darkest black I get is a medium grey.  I get this using both the built in ICC profile and also a custom ICC profile made with a SpyderPrint.  I am printing directly from Photoshop.

Any ideas what I could be causing the lack of deep blacks?

Comment: What does your calibration device say the maximum brightness of your monitor is?

Comment: @MichaelClark - I was calibrating the printer, but from back when I calibrated the monitor, I believe I have it set to 280 candles per inch (that may not be accurate as it is completely off the top of my head from an initial calibration I did over a year ago).

Comment: I tried viewing the Pixma Pro-1 manual online, but the download is an .exe that needs to be installed instead of a .pdf. I print on a lower grade Canon photo printer using matte paper and have no trouble getting dark blacks. I don't generally print from photoshop, though. Have you tried printing using the Canon print drivers directly? I'm also wondering if there is some sort of "ink saver" option for plain paper that may carry over to matte paper, but not photo paper.

Comment: @MichaelClark - it's worth a shot, though I was printing in Best quality rather than ink saver (it's a separate option for the Pro-1).  And yes, I'm not a big fan of the on-screen only manual either.

Comment: My offhand guess (assuming that this isn't just an optical effect from overbright, overdiffuse lighting on shiny-but-rough paper, and I have to assume you checked that) would be that it's using the wrong black for the paper for some reason (matte rather than photo or vice versa). I have no experience with the printer or the driver, so I don't know whether there's a setting that could be forcing one black or the other.

Comment: I have never seen truly good black on matte paper. I believe you when you say the printer is not doing it right, but even when you eventually fix the problem, the result perhaps will not be satisfactory anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some additional experimentation, I was able to determine there were two problems.  The first is that it is actually rather tricky to disable ICC profiles when printing the test patterns for my calibration.  Under the printing preferences, it is necessary to go to the Main tab and then select Manual color intensity.  It is then necessary to hit the Set button, go to the Matching tab and select "None".  This will remove any ICC profiles from being applied when printing calibration test patterns.

After calibrating, I was able to get a much better result, but the DMax is still really really bright.  It looks ok in a dimly lit viewing environment though and colors are otherwise ok when viewed in a dark environment.

Answer (score 2):

When choosing matte photo paper in the print box, the printer uses PHOTO black ink.  The ONLY way to get MATTE black in to work is to use one of cannons "fine art" paper selections.  I printed test prints on each setting using cannons color profiles each time using matte once and photo rag once.  Then used the manufacturers for photo rag and matte photo paper.

When everything was said ad done, the images with their 35mm margin had deep deep blacks and once printed full page using matte photo paper setting, blacks were black but dull as all get out.  Try it yourself.  I am glad I spent the money on the cartridges to figure this out.  People were complaining that the matte photos looked dull.

The engineers at canon (what a PITA they were to get to from the customer service reps) confirmed that the driver ONLY uses matte black ink when choosing a fine art paper drop down in the print box.

PS the only way to get the printer to use the "gray" inks is to tick "Grayscale" in the box before printing, otherwise uses black and other colors to create grays.

Dont take my word for it, try it yourself.  take a black image in a small box, print once with matte photo paper and then again with photo rag settings.  Use the same paper both times and same color profile.  You will see a HUGE diference!

Hope I could help anyone who stumbles upon this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of often getting a faded look from Canon's matte photo paper, while other times a nice, rich print emerged from the Pixma Pro-100. Finally, I figured out that the paper is coated on one side only!

It is difficult to tell the correct side to print on by looking at the paper, but one will be slightly whiter, the other being off-white or cream. Sometimes all you can do is try a print from one sheet of a ream, then be sure to face the remaining sheets the same way.